# How to tell if windows 8.1 update KB2883200-x64 is installed?

Tags: windows-update, visual-studio-2013

Hellp
I'm installing visual studio 2013 on a new, really new HP Probook Intel i5 and the installer crashes saying : **Visual Studio 2013 has stopped working ...**

Reading the Microsoft System requierements, I found that my computer fulfil them but I'm not sure to tell if the [KB2883200](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40749) is already installed or not.

- Can anyone tell me how to I tell if this Windows 8.1 update is installed or not?
- Why does VS2013 crash ?

Comment: If you are not sure then just install it.

Comment: It always not easy to download a ~127M file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can anyone tell me how to I tell if this Windows 8.1 update is installed or not?

Use the *Control Panel* and look in the update history found here:

```
 Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Windows Update\View update history
```

Comment: Thank you for this tip! I downloaded and installed but still doesn't appear in the windows update history.

Comment: That suggests to me it is not a Windows update. What exactly did you download?

Answer (score 0):

1. click on the folder icon in the taskbar. (File Explorer).
2. Right click on "This PC" and click on "Properties".
3. You should see your software and hardware information.